# Google Cloud SQL External Masters

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am new to Google Cloud Platform. I created a Cloud SQL first generation instance. I need help configuring an external master which is a local MySQL server.

1. I've prepared the data by doing a MySQL dump from the external master which is a local MySQL server.
2. I've uploaded the dump to a Cloud Storage Bucket.

I can't find any documentation that is clear enough on what to do next. I'm stuck. Any help will be really appreciated.

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

Its too late for giving the answer. But this will help others who all are looking to the solution for this.

Here is the blog which explain this: https://medium.com/searce/configure-external-master-for-cloudsql-replicate-vm-mysql-to-cloudsql-1f0e059e1cc6